# Grails: Groovy:unable to resolve class grails.test.mixin.TestFor

Tags: unit-testing, grails, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I'm a newbie in Grails.

In the unit tests which are generated automatically by Grails, there is import for grails.test.mixin

import grails.test.mixin.TestFor

However, STS complains on Groovy:unable to resolve class grails.test.mixin.TestFor
where is this class defined, and how should I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Right click in the project > grails tools > refresh dependencies. That solves your issue?

Comment: Did you find a solution. I have the same problem using Grails 2.3.7 and Grails Tool Suite 3.5. `Refresh dependencies` and `clean` project does not solve this.

Comment: Same problem with Grails 3.3 and Neon 3 with groovy eclipse feature.

Answer (score 2):

As Sérgio Michels suggests, run refresh dependencies on your project.  If that doesn't work, run Project -> Clean... on the project.

Also, make sure that you are using a compatible version of grails (ie- version 2.0 or later).